# How to say that I start doing something from this year/season

Tags: sentence-construction, time, dates, time-words

I would like to say that something starts at the particular moment, e.g. year or season. How should I pose it? For instance.

> I watched movies alone before, but starting from this winter, I plan
> to attend a cinema club.
>
> He always was a lazy couch potato, but since this month, he decided to
> go to a local gym for some reason.
>
> She didn't pay much attention to him before, but from the last Friday,
> she became more and more curios about his personality.

Comment: The first one sounds as though you haven't started attending the club yet, but the other two imply that the change has already happened. _[Ever] since last Friday, she's become more and more curious..._  If the gym visits started around the beginning of the month, you could say _This month he's started going to a local gym..._ It's _couch potato_, by the way.

Comment: Because you've already got the word ***starting*** in the first example, preposition ***from*** is optional / unnecessary: *I watched movies alone before, but starting this winter, I plan to attend a cinema club.* It would also be valid to omit ***starting*** and retain ***from***, but that would be a far less common stylistic choice. For things that started in the past rather than will start in the future, ***[ever] since, [as / starting] from*** are pretty much equivalent and interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first sentence is nearly correct.  All you need to do is drop the *from*.  The word *starting* already implies *from*.

> I used to watch movies alone but starting this winter I plan to attend a cinema club.

Your second sentence will be understood but probably is not the best way to phrase it.  *Since* best refers to things that happened in the past.  We cannot say *since tomorrow* or *since next winter* but we can say *since yesterday* and *since last winter*.

Using *since* for present can be understood, native speakers sometimes use it that way, but it is not a correct usage.

Using since correctly for a past start --

> He is a lazy couch potato but *since* last month he has been going to a gym.

Using since for the present (sounds awkward) --

> He is a lazy couch potato but *since* this month he has been going to a gym.

Keep in mind the multiple definitions of *since*. It can also be used to explain a person's motives.  The following usage has nothing to do with a time frame although it looks and sounds very similar to your sentence.

> He is a lazy couch potato but since this month is World Exercise Month, he is at the gym doing reps.

Using starting for the present --

> He is a lazy couch potato but *starting* this month he has been going to a gym.

Using starting for the past --

> He is a lazy couch potato but *starting* last month he has been going to a gym.

Using starting for the future --

> He is a lazy couch potato but *starting* next month he *will be* going to a gym.

Since your last sentence occurs in the past you can use either *since* or *starting* -- just be sure to the drop the word *from* and you do not need an article (no *the* or *a*).

> ...*since* last Friday.
> ...*starting* last Friday.

Answer (score 0):

An expression that could fit all of the examples you shared would be "as of":

> I watched movies alone before, but **as of** this winter, I plan to attend a cinema club.
>
> He always was a lazy coach potato, but **as of** this month, he decided to go to a local gym for some reason.
>
> She didn't pay much attention to him before, but **as of** last Friday, she became more and more curios about his personality.

"As of" is used to describe the onset of an action, such as the moment a decision is made, or the starting point for an ongoing commitment. It can be used to describe past, present, or future points in time, such as:

> As of last night, I am officially a pilot.
>
> I'm on a low-carb diet as of today.
>
> I'll be three years sober as of next month.

Reference: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/as-of)

Comment: From this/that date/time forward, I am/will be exercising on a regular basis.

Comment: @Sean Simon - Why are you suggesting the OP replace *starting* with *as of*?  Doesn't *starting*, the word provided by the OP,  work just as well?